# Passing value to form in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to pass the user_id contained in my database to a form that's displayed within a Bootstrap Modal upon clicking a button.

The button:

```
<td id="fired">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger btn-xs fired" data-id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>">
    Fired
  </button>
</td>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fired").click(function(){
        $("#user_id").val($(this).attr('data-id')); 
        $('#firedModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="firedModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="firedModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="firedModal">Fire Habbo</h4>
      </div>

      <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="" method="post">  
        <div class="modal-body">    
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Firing Reason" name="fired_reason" required autofocus />
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Firing Tag" name="fired_tag" required />
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="fired_date" required />
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Status (MAY JOIN AS RECRUIT/PARDONED/NEVER REHIRE)" name="fired_status" />
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_id" value="" />
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Fire</button>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, on clicking the button the modal shows but the value of the user_id input is not filled by the row's user_id. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You are calling `#user_id` but there is no `id="user_id"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your code , with this one.

```
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="" />


    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#fired").click(function(){
         $("#user_id").val($(this).attr('data-id')); 
         $('#firedModal').modal('show');
       });
    });
```

Comment: Very useful , helped solved a similar issue, using this but changing jquery click to  on.